# Groovy: stub typed reference

Tags: groovy, stubbing

I have a Groovy class similar to

```
class MyClass {

  Foo foo
}
```

Under certain circumstances I don't want to initialize foo and want to stub out all the calls to it. Any methods that return a value should do nothing. I could do it like this:

```
Foo.metaClass.method1 = {param -> }
Foo.metaClass.method2 = { -> }
Foo.metaClass.method3 = {param1, param2 -> }
```

While this will work, it has a couple of problems

1. Tedious and long-winded, particularly if Foo has a lot of methods
2. This will stub out calls to any instance of Foo (not just foo)

Although Groovy provides a StubFor class, if I do this:

```
this.foo = new groovy.mock.interceptor.StubFor(Foo)
```

I get a ClassCastException at runtime. Although this would work if I could redefine foo as:

```
def foo
```

But for reasons I won't go into here, I can't do that.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Foo instance to your MyClass object. In the test, pass in a stub implementation. In the real program pass in a real implementation.

You don't need any special framework to write the stub. If you're only stubbing queries to Foo and are not interested in *expecting* commands to it, then it's easier to write a stub implementation by hand. A mock object library is overkill and will confuse later readers of the code who will expect the test to include expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is for test purposes only.

The line:

```
Foo foo
```

creates a getter / setter pair, so you can inject a mock in your test cases by doing this:

```
new MyClass().foo = new MockFoo()
```

If you don't want to create the mock for yourself, try a mocking library. I recommend using [mockito](http://mockito.org/). With this small library you can do something like this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
new MyClass().foo = mock(Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
this.foo = {Object[] args -> println "I don't do anything"} as Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a stub with a map as well, making it possible to stub multiple methods, like so:

```
def stubbedList = [empty : { false }, get: {index -> "always return this"}] as ArrayList
```

If you stub out a class (like in the ArrayList example above), then the methods that you do not override are kept as they are implemented in the class. You can also stub out interfaces obviously.

If you are in need of mocking capabilities (i.e verifying behaviour in a test, like counting the number of calls to a given method), I would strongly recommend checking out the [Spock test framework](http://spockframework.org). It has really great support for more advanced stubbing and mocking.